# How to easily change the layout of the screen from Portrait to Landscape and vice versa in WPF

Tags: wpf, layout, screen, orientation, screen-rotation

Let's suppose we have the designed the layout of some WPF application to be used on standard Full HD screen 1920x1080. Then we need to rotate the screen and install it in a box that is mounted on kiosk PC but in Portrait orientation.

I need to find a way on how to rotate the screen easily or at least in some more elegant way.

I tried to use use RenderTransform and RotateTransform applied to the contents of the window but this rotates the image and of course not the layout.

The controls remain of the same width and height.

Is there a way to do it automatically or should I take each control and change it properties one by one ?

The problem is present for TextBlocks and TextBoxes. They are intended to be used horizontally. You can rotate it but the layout is calculated based to it's horizontal width.

BTW. Rotation of the entire window is not allowed. It throws an exception.

Comment: The video drivers don't allow you to rotate everything?

Comment: I am doing this for a client and we do not have the possibility to do it through the drivers. But maybe if we find a suitable drivers this can be the last option to take. I am now searching what is the difference between LayoutTransform and RenderTransform and maybe this can help me. Not sure at the moment.

Comment: So in the Kiosk everything else is going to be sideways?

Comment: if you found a solution to your own problem, please post it an an answer to this question, instead of editing the question with that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that I have found the solution myself. If we choose the Layout transform instead of RenderTransform then the visual system does the arrangement and measurement of the layout automatically before the rendering.

The WPF framework does the job in this order

LayoutTransform
Measure
Arrange
RenderTransform
Render

This is best described here [LAYOUTTRANSFORM VS. RENDERTRANSFORM - WHAT'S THE DIFFERENCE?](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/19/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference.html)